SSAS return multiple date
There is a date attribute in the SSAS membership card file dimension, called "valid date to end date". Select the attributes of the member master file, the membership card file's "valid date to end date", the member card file's value, and finally the "valid date to end date" will list the dates of all member card files at the same time. What should I do to list only one?
Note: The relationship between the member master file and the member card file is one-to-many and is related by member number.
